# How to write/read and manipulate microsoft access databases

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, file-writing

I was wondering how i could easily read and write to Microsoft access files.
I have to be able to create and write to it with 2 variables(depending on inputs during the program) and then if this person repeats this more than 3 times it must only store the last the three inputs they do but all this must be done in access.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, the answer depends a little on your situation, and the technology you are using. In general, I would look at using ADO. You would reference ADO in your application, and then connect to the Access DB using a connection string.

Which technology are you using to try and connect?

Check out this article and let me know if it helps:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168336

Comment: i am using python. this webpage looks good but it would need to be converted with the correct modules.

Comment: PYODBC may work as well 
http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

import pyodbc
db_file = r'''C:\x.mdb'''
user = 'admin'
password = ''
odbc_conn_str = 'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s' % \
                (db_file, user, password)
conn = pyodbc.connect(odbc_conn_str)